# SpringBoot Graceful shut with returning exit code

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a class like below

```
public class GracefulShutdown implements TomcatConnectorCustomizer, ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent> {

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GracefulShutdown.class);
  private volatile Connector connector;

  @Override
  public void customize(Connector connector) {
    this.connector = connector;
  }

  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(ContextClosedEvent contextClosedEvent) {
    log.info("Protocol handler is shutting down");
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    System.exit(exitCode);
}
```

where exitCode can be 0 or 1. I am not getting that exit code in shell Script $?.
Kindly guide why I am not getting it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don’t know how graceful works but I guess you have to register your class somewhere or tag it with a particular annotation so graceful will know what to run (your class methods) when the contex is closed, otherwise it is just a class that is not being used. Hope that help

Comment: @Iman: True.we have to add to TomcatServletWebServerFactory.addConnectorCustomizers(gracefulShutdown );